# Filter works in Spark AR simulator, but not in app?

Tags: instagram, spark-ar-studio

So basically when I build and test in the simulator, it works fine. This includes the simulator for phone and the one in the program. However, when I create an instagram link it doesn't work at all, doesn't even say the name of the filter at the top when selected. What should I do? It used to work.

Answer (score 0):

Does your filter include segmentation?
This may be it as Instagram's segmentation is not supported in majority of devices